# Applying Angular filter from different view & controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm an angular newbie so forgive me if the question title isn't very helpful.

I have a div with ng-repeat that I want to perform filters on, but the filtered elements exists in a separate view and uses a separate controller from the filter button.

On the landing page, I have a button that does this:

`<div class="evaweb-nav" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <div class="view-indicator" ng-click="actionFilter = { userFavorite : 'true' };">
</div>`

The elements I want filtered exists in a separate view & uses `libraryCtrl` by routeProvider

`<div class="video-item" ng-repeat="chirp in chirps | filter: actionFilter | filter: categoryFilter | filter: searchFilter"></div>`

If I replace `actionFilter` with `{ userFavorite : 'true' }`, it works just fine, but otherwise it won't work.

I also tried putting it inside of a factory, and injected it into `libraryCtrl` (see below)

```
demoApp.factory('filterFactory', function() {
    var actionFilter = { userFavorite : 'true' };

    var factory = {};
    factory.getFilter = function() {
        return actionFilter;
    }

   return factory;
});
```

`libraryCtrl` is able to read `actionFilter`, but it's not applying it to the filter in the view. I'm pretty much out of moves, should I be structuring it differently? What am I doing wrong?

**Addition**

`actionFilter` is defined in both the factory and the mainCtrl;

`ng-repeat` occurs in libraryCtrl.

The factory is injected into both libraryCtrl and mainCtrl, (I was hoping this would allow libraryCtrl to access the scope of mainCtrl)

Comment: That is probably because you are defining `actionFilter` scope property inside the scope of mainCtrl. and your ng-repeat is elsewhere (based on the snippet that you have pasted in the quesiton.)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include: `actionFilter` is defined in both the factory and the mainCtrl; the ng-repeat occurs in libraryCtrl. The factory is injected into both libraryCtrl and mainCtrl.

Comment: why are you changing the whole object in `ng-clcik` and not just changing a property? Suggest you create a simple demo that replicates your problem